# File sharing service with an API?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, dropbox, file-sharing

Is there a file sharing service akin to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) that would offer an API? I would like to add a file sharing service to a website, but the full Dropbox interface is still too complicated for my users, so that I’d like an API to build a dead-simple list of files integrated to the website. There is a [Dropbox API project](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-api/) on Google Code, but it seems to be dead.

---

*Update:* I need a service with a desktop client at least for Windows, so that the more technical website users could easily upload and organize the stored data. Extra points if the service has a free plan.

Comment: Try https://cloudinary.com/ they are good. Their API's are easy to understand and integrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick **[search on ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=file%20storage)** brings up about 50 API results.

<s>Out of the lot, I could only say that I have had experience with the **[Box.net](http://www.box.net/developers)** website. I've had no trouble in the past, and they have rather acceptable limits for the free account (25 MB per file; 1 GB of storage).</s>

I'm sure that with a little poking around you'll find something that fits your needs, but I wouldn't expect to find something that offers you a business-scale solution for free, you might have to be prepared to make an investment, and in that case some of **[Amazon's Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/)** might be better suited to your needs.

**Edit:** Since I answered this question 6 years ago, the landscape for storage solutions with APIs has changed somewhat. There are now free or affordable services with mature developer APIs offered by [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/), [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), [Rackspace CloudFiles](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/resources), [Microsoft Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx) and for mobile, [iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/).

Comment: ProgrammableWeb is very nice, thank you. I initially forgot about S3 as I wanted a service with a desktop client, but only after reading your answer I realized there are S3 desktop clients from third parties. I’ll take a look at it, thank you once more.

Comment: Box.net does not have free subscription anymore !!

Comment: Thanks @MohammadAsmar - this was originally asked over 6 years ago, I've updated to hopefully give a more appropriate answer given today's offerings. Feel free to suggest additional edits for other services if they are more appropriate.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the date, it's fair enough now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We are a file sharing company that has recently released a fully functioning RESTful API. You can add users, groups, permissions, files, dynamic links and even searching in real-time.  Unlike [dropbox](/questions/tagged/dropbox) and [sugarsync](/questions/tagged/sugarsync) it was designed for business, thus giving you multi-user access.

We would love your feedback.

http://www.smartfile.com/dev/

[smartfile](/questions/tagged/smartfile)

Comment: Your REST API for uploading a file sucks honestly and I wasted many hours  around it

Comment: I too wasted a bunch of time with smartfile. They don't support CORS!

Answer (score 1):

I used https://uploadcare.com and it works like a charm.

Comment: The free account only supports images :-(