# What is the best way to share relatively big files in android? (No database!)

Tags: android

I'm wondering what the best way to share multiple images and text in one-go. The text belongs to the images as descriptions

I have researched some and you can convert images to binary, place them in a json file and open certain files with your app, read the text and convert the binary back to bitmaps.

However this requires you to send a file with multiple binary images, which can grow a bit big. It is also cpu intensive

I was thinking of sharing these files over e-mail or whatsapp, but my question is: **Is there any better way to do this?**

Comment: What do you mean by "one-go"? Also, what do you mean by "sharing"? Do you mean sharing with another user who is using your app? Or sharing data with other apps on the device? Or sharing data between activities / fragments? Or just sharing stuff on social media?

Comment: @stefan did you mean you have multiple data text and imges yu need to share them via whatsapp or email??

Comment: @Ryan i meant sharing it with other users that use the app, so sending them a file through email or whatsapp, that they can then open with the app and import

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is to let the user share the file using an application of their choice, just like you said.

Other possible solutions are:

1. Upload the file to your own server and let it expire after some time.
2. Use a [file sharing service API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452602/file-sharing-service-with-an-api)

However these will take more time to implement and most of them might cost you money.